# ActiveRecord Scoped Uniqueness Validations vs MySQL Compound Unique Indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

First, let me set the stage:

I have an `app_settings` table that joins `app_setting_options` with `user_id`, `user_role_id`, `event_id`, `group_id`, or `app_level_setting`. For any given `app_setting` there should be a specific `app_setting_option_id` and only **one** of those other objects. For each one of those secondary objects, I have specified a uniqueness validation with a scope in the `AppSetting` model:

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :user_role_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :group_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :event_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :app_level_setting, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
```

On top of all that, I also have in place a compound unique index on each of the secondary objects in the database. Normally I would just rely on ActiveRecord validations to take care of any weird edge case scenarios, but (long story short) there tends to be a decent amount of direct database adjustments that happen and we want to stop something unintended from happening.

In my tests, I create an `app_setting` with a specific `app_setting_option` and a specific `user_id` and then try to do the exact same thing again. Validations stops that from happening. It works flawlessly with `user_role`, `event`, and `group` as well. The problem is with the `app_level_setting` where it somehow makes it past validations and gets stopped by the compound unique index at the database level, getting a `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry`.

```
it 'app_level_setting uniqueness' do
  app_setting_option = AppSettingOption.find(21)
  create(:app_setting, app_setting_option: app_setting_option, app_level_setting: 1)
  create(:app_setting, app_setting_option: app_setting_option, app_level_setting: 1)
end
```

The 2nd app_setting is not created because of the index on the database, not because of the validations. Is there something specific about uniqueness validations on a boolean? I get the same error when I try to create an identical `app_level_setting` in the console as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to create a custom validation as follows:

```
validate :app_level_setting_validation

def app_level_setting_validation
  errors.add(:app_setting, "app level setting already exists") if app_setting_option.app_setting_type_id == 1 && AppSetting.find_by(app_setting_option_id: app_setting_option.id, app_level_setting: true).present?
end
```

And then my test was as follows:

```
it 'App level setting uniqueness' do
  app_setting_option = create(:app_setting_option)
  create(:app_setting, app_setting_option: app_setting_option, app_level_setting: true)
  setting = build(:app_setting, app_setting_option: app_setting_option, app_level_setting: true)
  setting.should_not be_valid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For boolean field validations you can not set uniquesness validation.
For validating boolean fields, you can do something like,

```
validates :field, :inclusion => {:in => [true, false]}
```

Comment: Is it possible to scope that? I want to make sure that for any specific `app_setting_option_id` there can only be one record with app_level_setting == true. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can scope with app_setting_option_id.

Comment: Ok, but what is the syntax for that? Where does the scope go?