# Rails Validations: Scoped Uniqueness on a Boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Based on [this previous question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384297/activerecord-scoped-uniqueness-validations-vs-mysql-compound-unique-indexes), I understand that it is not possible to use a standard scoped uniqueness on a boolean field. With a boolean you must use an inclusion validation, but then I can't figure out how to scope that inclusion to another field in the table.

Here's the simplest way I can think to describe it.

I have `app_settings` and `app_setting_options` tables. The `app_settings` takes a given `app_option_option` and either a `user_id`, `user_role_id`, `group_id`, `event_id`, or `app_level`. All of them have a scoped uniqueness validation, so there can be only one record with a specific `user_id` and specific `app_setting_option`. The problem is that the `app_level` field is a boolean, I don't know how to scope that uniqueness (true or false) to a `app_setting_option`.

Here are my validations as is right now:

```
validates :app_setting_option_id, presence: true
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :user_role_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :group_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :event_id, uniqueness: { scope: :app_setting_option_id}, allow_nil: true
validates :app_level_setting, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }, allow_nil: true
```

What is the syntax for uniqueness with a scope for that last one?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misreading the question, but if you want to allow one `app_setting` with a given `user_id` when `app_level_setting` is `true`, and one `app_setting` with a given `user_id` when `app_level_setting` is `false`, you can use an array to the `scope`, like `scope: [:app_setting_option_id, :app_level_setting]`.

If you want `app_level_setting` to have a scope similar to the rest, you probably have to do it manually, with something like `validate :app_level_setting_scope` and creating the method `app_level_setting_scope` to add an error if the record is not unique. You'll have to do the queries and logic on your own.

The [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) have some documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I see some confusion there. With a given app_setting_option, there will be only ONE of user_id, user_role_id, event_id, group_id, or app_level_setting. That's why this is weird because for those first 4 fields, there is an id supplied, but for app_level_setting, it is either true or false. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yeah, then option 2 should work.

Create a custom validation method that gets called, have it return without doing anything if either of the ID fields are populated, and if none of them are, do your check to make sure `app_level_setting` is unique for the given `app_setting_option_id`.